# Could not find class `javax.naming.ldap.LdapName` referenced from method `com.mashape.relocation.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.extractCN`

Tags: java, android, unirest

I have the following example activity:

```
package teste.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);
        try {
            text.setText(Unirest.get("http://google.com").asString().getBody());
        }catch (UnirestException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I compiled Unirest from the source following the [official guide](http://blog.mashape.com/using-unirest-java-for-your-android-projects/) and ended up with a `.jar` named `unirest-java-1.4.6-SNAPSHOT-withDependency-ShadedForAndroid.jar`.

When I run the activity, it immediately breaks with the error on the title. Here's the full stacktrace (logcat with Error filter):

```
04-03 10:50:55.150    1767-1767/teste.myapplication E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'javax.naming.ldap.LdapName', referenced from method com.mashape.relocation.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.extractCNs
04-03 10:50:55.170    1767-1767/teste.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: teste.myapplication, PID: 1767
    java.lang.VerifyError: com/mashape/relocation/conn/ssl/AbstractVerifier
            at com.mashape.relocation.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:126)
            at com.mashape.relocation.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getDefaultRegistry(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:98)
            at com.mashape.relocation.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:105)
            at com.mashape.unirest.http.options.Options.refresh(Options.java:73)
            at com.mashape.unirest.http.options.Options.<clinit>(Options.java:46)
            at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.prepareRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:154)
            at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:134)
            at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asString(BaseRequest.java:56)
            at teste.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "teste.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile files('libs/unirest-java-1.4.6-SNAPSHOT-withDependency-ShadedForAndroid.jar')
}
```

I don't know what could be. I tried recompiling the library already, but I had no change.

Comment: This class has been part of the JDK since at least 1.4, which is 13 years ago.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) which worked like a charm.

In the end, though, the error went away in an AVD running API 21 (I was previously testing on an AVD running API 19, and my phone was also on 19), maybe updating is key, but if your application targets API 19 and lower, and you can't change the library, then I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

On your android device, go to "settings", "about software", "system updates", "update"

Comment: why should that help him? Please explain.

Comment: For what is worth, the error goes away on a Nexus 5 AVD with API 21 (I was testing with my phone which is running KitKat API 19, and my AVD was on 19 as well.). It got replaced with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, so _maybe_ that version of Unirest doesn't play nice with API 19? In the end, see my own answer.